# HC-0# Bluetooth module questions

Tags: bluetooth

I've been playing with the HC-06 BT module lately, but now I want to do more with it and I'm not sure how to. I was wondering if it's possible to get signal strength from the module, or would I have to purchase another HC-0# module to do so? Also the HC-05, can initiate connection if I'm understanding documentation right, and return available devices in the area?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was wondering if it's possible to get signal strength from the module

No, it doesn't appear so from the data sheet / AT command list.

> Also the HC-05, can initiate connection if I'm understanding documentation right, and return available devices in the area?

Yes, and it can get the signal strengths.  You should be able to get an HC-05 module on a breakout board from Ebay for less than $10 delivered.  There's also a method to update the HC-06 firmware to be an HC-05 but it's probably easier for you to buy one.